Find all elements of Automorphism on a simply connected domain
Find a conformal map from $U = \mathbb{D}_1(0)−[0, 1)$ to the upper half plane, and use it to find all elements of Aut$(U)$ that fix the point $(2\sqrt{2} − 3) \in U$
My approach:
First we take a $\phi \in $Aut$(\mathbb{D}_1(0))$ which has the following form
$$\phi(z)=a \dfrac{z-p}{1-\overline{p}z}$$
Then I post compose with the inverse of the Cayley map
$$\psi= \dfrac{i(1-z)}{1+z}$$
Hence I have $\psi \circ \phi (z) $ is a biholomorphic map from $\mathbb{D}_1(0)$ toe the upper half plane which gives
$$\psi \circ \phi (z)= \dfrac{i(1-a \dfrac{z-p}{1-\overline{p}z})}{1+a \dfrac{z-p}{1-\overline{p}z}}$$
If I consider the cayley map $\psi ^{-1} = \dfrac{i-z}{i+z}$
that goes from upper half plane to unit disc and I want it to omit $t$ such that $0\leq t<1$.
I solved to omits $[0,1]=)$ my $z\neq \dfrac{i-t}{i+t}$ for $t\in [0,1)$
Now, I am lost at how do I incorporate the part where this function do not take in the unit interval? shouldnt the composition works anyway as a restriction on $U$?
